# document.activeelement not recognising anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry i was not able to find good title for the question. I have onblur event on my textbox which checks for duplicate name. I dont want to check for duplicate name if i click on button or a anchor tag after losing focus from input. So i use following code to check if i clicked on button or anchor tag

```
if (document.activeElement === $('#btnSubmit')[0] || document.activeElement === $('#testLink')[0]) return;
```

But it doesnt recognises anchor tag and goes on displaying message. I dont want to show message when i click on anchor tag after use tabs out from input.

To replicate scenario.

1. Click on textbox
2. Then tab out.
3. Click on anchor tag and you will get message box. I dont want message box when i click on anchor tag.

Why document.activeElement is not able to find anchor tag. Please help me

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3uNP/183/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor tag cannot be focused by default. You have to set `tabindex` attribute, e.g:

```
<a id="testLink" href="#" tabindex="-1">Test</a>
```

You could wish to remove the outline in CSS:

```
a{outline:0}
```

All in one, using jQuery:

```
$('#testLink').attr('tabindex',-1).css('outline',0);
```

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3uNP/185/)

Comment: That is perfect and thats what i wanted.I want to know why we need to remove outline in CSS and what is it?

Comment: outline is just for styling, it's kind of border which appears on focused element. You don't need to remove it if you don't care about it